# matplotlib.pyplot Error in PyCharm Community

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, matplotlib, pycharm

I already downloaded matplotlib on the PyCharm Community IDE ... anyway when I try to use this code

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 year = [1940 , 1960 , 1980 , 2000]
 pop = [2.5 , 3.6 , 5.2 , 7.1]
      plt.plot(year,pop)
     plt.show()
```

I got this error

' No module named matplotlib '

I downloaded matplotlib from terminal and I did in PyCharm Community

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/13af6ef/pycharm_saying_no_module_named_matplotlib/

Answer (score 0):

1. [Create a virtualenv](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html)
2. [Install matplotlib](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)
3. Fix your indentation. (Last two lines seem off.)
4. Run again.